# string to indexed property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a, next to a couple of fixed options, a variable number of yes/no radio inputs named `other[index]`. Using `$(form).serializeArray()` I get an array of name/value objects. Using reduce I'm able to reduce em down to an actual object.

```
const seializedForm = $(event.currentTarget.form).serializeArray();

const gdpr = seializedForm.reduce((aggragation, option) => { 
    return {
        ...aggragation,
        [option.name]: option.value === 'true'
}}, {});
```

The problem here is that the result isn't exactly what I need:

```
{
  "canNotify":true,
  "canContact":true,
  "canProcess":true,
  "other[0]":false,
  "other[1]":true,
  "other[2]":false
}
```

I'd like it to be:

```
{
  "canNotify":true,
  "canContact":true,
  "canProcess":true,
  "other": [
      false,
      true,
      false
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each name - remove the brackets, and if the key already exists in the array, combine the values to an array using array spread:

```js
const serializedForm = [{"name":"canNotify","value":"true"},{"name":"canContact","value":"true"},{"name":"canProcess","value":"false"},{"name":"other[0]","value":"false"},{"name":"other[1]","value":"true"},{"name":"other[2]","value":"false"}];

const gdpr = serializedForm.reduce((aggragation, { name, value }) => {
  const isArray = name.includes('[');
  const key = name.replace(/\[.+\]/g, '');
  const val = value === 'true';

  return {
    ...aggragation,
    [key]: isArray ? [...aggragation[key] || [], val] : val
  };
}, {});

console.log(gdpr);
```

Comment: @customcommander - Yep. It should always be an array, even if it has one item. Fixed.

Comment: I was hoping for a way without processing strings but this does the trick and is the most complete answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the full object structure looks like, why not just check what the name contains before returning, if the name contains the array syntax. `[]` or the string `other`, then we can assume that it is part of the other form collection structure?

```
const seializedForm = $(event.currentTarget.form).serializeArray();

const gdpr = seializedForm.reduce((aggragation, option) => {
    if (isInArrayOfOptions(option)) {
        return {
            ...aggragation,
            /* Return a new array combining the current with the next option.value*/
            'other': [...aggragation.other, ...[option.value === 'true']]
        }
    }
    return {
        ...aggragation,
        [option.name]: option.value === 'true'
    }
}, {});
```